# How do i lock a channel that is mentioned? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is my code, It only locks the current channel I'm in, I feel a bit stupid as i think i should know this lol. For example, I want to say '-lock #channelname but it only locks my current channel.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None):
    overwrite = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    overwrite.send_messages = False
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
    await ctx.send('Channel locked.')
@lock.error
async def lock_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error,commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send('You do not have permission to use this command!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two channel objects involved: `ctx.channel` which is the channel the command was invoked in, or `channel` which is the channel that was passed as part of the command invocation. Below is some code for using `channel` if it's available, otherwise using `ctx.channel`

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel=None):
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    overwrite.send_messages = False
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
    await ctx.send('Channel locked.')
```

Comment: ah yes, thank you. I was along the right lines and has actually used "channel = channel or ctx.channel" at some point but must have had something else slightly wrong at the time. Appreciate it

Comment: This works in some servers. But nowadays many servers have verification systems and when this command blocks sending msgs it won't affect on users because they have another role. So is there any method to block sending messages except the users that have 'manage_messages` permisson?