# (Discord.py) How to lock and unlock voice channel

Tags: permissions, discord.py, locking, channel, voice

I'm a newbie in programming. After hours in Stackoverflow and YouTube, I have created Bot, which allows auto-create temporary voice channels, for all server users (any roles) and delete this channels when they empty.

```
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    person_freq=['1', '2', '3']
    person = member.name
    
    if member.bot:
        return
    if str(after.channel) == "+ NEW":

        if str(after) != str(before):
            guild = member.guild
            freq = person_freq[0]
            act_voice_channels = (c.name for c in guild.voice_channels)
            for freq in person_freq:
                if freq not in act_voice_channels:
                    await after.channel.clone(name=freq)
                    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.voice_channels, name=freq)
                    await member.move_to(channel)
                    return
        
    if len(before.channel.members) == 0: 
        await before.channel.delete()
```

I purposely removed part of the code with other 'IF' conditions.

Now I want to add permissions to members who create each particular channel a local admin role. And remove it after the channel will be deleted. This local admin will need to be able to 'lock' and 'unlock' his own voice_channel.
In case of the "lock"-command, nobody except server Admins allows joining the channel.
In case of the "unlock"-command - this prohibition is lifted.

I suppose that I need write smtn in this two defs

```
#lock
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(**administrator**=True)
async def lock(ctx):



#unlock
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(**administrator**=True)
async def unlock(ctx):
```

How I can do it, considering that there may be many such channels?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62706813/how-do-i-lock-a-channel-that-is-mentioned-discord-py) help you? Instead of ```ctx.channel``` use ```ctx.voice_channel```.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'Voice_channel'

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.Guild.voice_channels)

Comment: voice_channel is for guild but not for ctx

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/869) on GitHub. Take reference from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ChaoticNebula for sharing same issue on GitHub. I did some correction due to new version of discord.py and solve this issue:

```
#lock
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge (limit=1)
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    overwrite.connect = False
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)


#unlock
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unlock(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge (limit=1)
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    overwrite.connect = True
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
```